# How to generate reports from a blazor .NET Core 3 project?

Tags: .net-core, report, blazor

I have tried to use various tools to create reports but they all have licenses, I use a free tool.

Try using FastReport but it doesn't seem to support Blazor.

I need a tool with a report viewer to be able to design the report graphically.

Comment: Use any free JS library and use Blazor IJSRuntime to invoke.

Comment: But which ?
I don't know any